# Using Data from a JSON response

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to make a program that uses an API that gives a JSON response that looks something like this:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "available_balance" : "0.1137",
    "datastuff" : "0.0000",
    "moredata" : "0.1137",
  }
}
```

So my program looks something like this:

```
import json
jsonbaldata = ""
mytoken = ""

def getbal():
    jsonbaldata = json.loads("https://website.com/api/apinformationhere/?api_key=" + APIKey + "&code=" + my_token)
    print("Balance: " + available_balance)
    return;

print("Starting program...")
getbal()
```

I edited a lot of it out as it doesn't pertain to the question and is private, but the main question is, once I call the `jsonbaldata`, how can I use the variables it gives to me later in the program? For example, say I wanted to print `available_balance`, how would I change the JSON data into usable python data?

Also, am I even calling the API correctly to do this? or is `json.loads` not a good way to do this/there is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: two things a) call api using request b) the response u get load it as json and iterate..you cannot json.loads(a url)

Comment: `json.loads` does not perform Web requests. You need a different library for that.

Comment: Also, try reading the Python json documentation. It answers your other questions

Comment: what is `available_balance` ? where it is defined ?

Comment: has some problems ... try reading the json documentation

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi available_balance is something that I get from the JSON data from the API.

Comment: so it must called in this way : `jsonbaldata ['data']['available_balance']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use an actual GET request to pull in the API data first. Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for this.

You'd load the data like so:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://website.com/api/apinformationhere/", params={'api_key': APIKey, 'code': my_token})
data = r.json()[0]
```

You can then access data as a python dict, i.e.

```
print(data['data']['available_balance'])
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your data:**

```
   js ={
      "status" : "success",
      "data" : {
        "available_balance" : "0.1137",
        "datastuff" : "0.0000",
        "moredata" : "0.1137",
      }
    }
```

Q."How can I use the variables it gives to me later in the program".  "Say I wanted to print available_balance, how would I change the JSON data into usable python data?".

A. You have a python dictionary and access the data as follows:

```
js['data']['available_balance']
```

**Output:**

'0.1137'

I would also recommend you read the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) as it has example like this one which may help you:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
r.json()
```

**Output:**

```
[{u'repository': {u'open_issues': 0, u'url': 'https://github.com/...
```